# ¿Cómo puedo validar y enviar un formulario en HTML a un correo solo utilizando PHP?

Tags: php, html

Esté es mi código, quiero enviarlo a mi cuenta de correo ya validado únicamente con php por que se que con JS pueden desactivar su JS y mi validación no sería útil lo que quiero es evitar spammeos y skiddies y de ser posible que si el campo no es llenado correctamente salte una alerta, gracias.

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
  <h3 class="title-section" style="width: 100%;">Dejanos tu mensaje</h3>
    <ul id="form">
      <li>
        <label>Nombre</label>
        <input name="nombre" type="text" placeholder="Nombre" ?>"  />
      </li>
      <br>
      <li>
        <label>T&eacute;lefono</label>
        <input name="telefono" type="text" placeholder="Télefono"/>
      </li>
      <br>
      <li>
        <label>Email</label>
        <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email"/>
      </li>
      <br>
      <li>
        <label>C.P.</label>
        <input name="cp" type="text" placeholder="C.P."/>
      </li>
      <br>
      <li>
        <label>Mensaje</label>
        <textarea name="mensaje" rows="6" cols="40" placeholder="Dejanos tú mensaje."></textarea>
      </li>
      <br>
      <li>
        <td><input name="boton" type="submit" value="Enviar" /></td>
      </li>
    </ul>
 </form>
```

Comment: No se se si influya en algo pero, es una cuenta de outlook a la que lo quiero hacer llegar.

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Hasta que no añadas mas información, me temo que tu pregunta quedará [en espera-¿Qué significa si una pregunta está "cerrada" o "en espera"?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), pero si editas tu pregunta y la mejoras, la comunidad puede optar por abrirla y darte una solución. Saludos.

Comment: El código que colocas es solo un formulario html sin relación con la pregunta. El ejemplo debe mostrar que estás haciendo para resolver tu problema o permitir observar el error que se presenta. Con el código que se agregó no se puede reproducir el problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo tienes que capturar de los name="" y enviarlos por POST.

**HTML**

```
<form action="validacion.php" method="post">
```

**PHP** (validacion.php)

```
  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
    }
  }
```

Más información: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_url_email.asp